# Calling lookup in Initialize before scene render

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to use the code below to synchronize scroll bars.

```
Node n1 = listView1.lookup(".scroll-bar");
if (n1 instanceof ScrollBar) {
    final ScrollBar bar1 = (ScrollBar) n1;
    Node n2 = listView2.lookup(".scroll-bar");
    if (n2 instanceof ScrollBar) {
        final ScrollBar bar2 = (ScrollBar) n2;
        bar1.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(bar2.valueProperty());
    }
}
```

I would like to run these lines of code inside the `Initialize()` method of the scene.
Unfortunately, these lines of codes require that the scene has been rendered. 
Is there a way to run these lines after the scene has been rendered without any user input?

Answer (score 1):

This ugly hack seems to work:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView1 ;
    @FXML
    private ListView<String> listView2 ;

    @FXML
    private Parent root ;

    public void initialize() {
        root.sceneProperty().addListener((obs, oldScene, newScene)  -> {
           if (newScene != null) {
               root.applyCss();
               Node n1 = listView1.lookup(".scroll-bar");
               System.out.println(n1);
               if (n1 instanceof ScrollBar) {
                   final ScrollBar bar1 = (ScrollBar) n1;
                   Node n2 = listView2.lookup(".scroll-bar");
                   System.out.println(n2);
                   if (n2 instanceof ScrollBar) {
                       final ScrollBar bar2 = (ScrollBar) n2;
                       bar1.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(bar2.valueProperty());
                   }
               }

           }
        });

    }
}
```